# Get next element outside span

Tags: javascript, removechild

I have the following code:

```
<span class='myClass'>My Text</span><button class='myBtn'>OK</button>
<span class='myClass'>My Text</span><button class='myBtn'>OK</button>
<span class='myClass'>My Text</span><button class='myBtn'>OK</button>
```

I'm looking to click on any of myClass and remove it's contents PLUS remove button right after that. I don't want to remove others - just the one I click on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    $(this).next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

If plain javascript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was missing the next() in my cod. Thank you.